# Correctly passing a path from zsh (cygwin) to vim on windows

Tags: vim, zsh

I have the following alias/function in my `.zshrc` to open gvim with file names as arguments.

```
vim() { 
    if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
        gvim "$*";
    else 
        gvim;
    fi
}
```

It opens files in `~` just fine, but when I try to pass a path, it doesn't work. For example, from a zsh I say `vim ~/dir/test1.txt` (a file which exists on `C:\Users\myname\dir\test1.txt`) and gvim opens with the following file `\c\Users\myname\dir\test1.txt` [NEW DIRECTORY] which doesn't exist? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cygpath](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html) might help here, like this:

```
gvim `cygpath -w $*`
```

Comment: fantastic! thanks so much for this should have rtfm but you got it!